# jqgrid onclickSubmitLocal using ajax

Tags: jqgrid

I am using the example [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditing2.htm) as a starting point. Everything works fine, I can submit the data back to the server and get a response. However I don't know how to connect the callback from the ajax to the jqgrid onclickSubmitLocal. I don't want to use alerts because even if there is an error the row is updated. I would like some how if there is an error the modal edit dialog to show the error and prevent it from updating the row. On success I would like the user to get a message saying data was saved.
Here is the relevant code:

```
       function submitData(rowData){
            var dataToSend = JSON.stringify(rowData);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/save',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: dataToSend,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(' successfully saved.');
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    alert('Error processing submit  ' + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
    }
```

I called the previous function from

```
                onclickSubmitLocal = function (options, postdata) {
                var $this = $(this), p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"),// p = this.p,
                    idname = p.prmNames.id,
                    id = this.id,
                    idInPostdata = id + "_id",
                    rowid = postdata[idInPostdata],
                    addMode = rowid === "_empty",
                    oldValueOfSortColumn,
                    newId,
                    idOfTreeParentNode;

                ... same as in example from link above

                if (postdata[p.sortname] !== oldValueOfSortColumn) {
                    // if the data are changed in the column by which are currently sorted
                    // we need resort the grid
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $this.trigger("reloadGrid", [{current: true}]);
                    }, 100);
                }

                // !!! the most important step: skip ajax request to the server
                options.processing = true;
                submitData([postdata]);
            },
```

Comment: Please include in all questions about jqGrid the information about the **version** of jqGrid, which you use and the **fork**, which you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). I created the demo, which you referenced, many years ago at the time when jqGrid didn't supported local editing. Local editing is supported out-of-the-box later. Moreover, jqGrid supports saving edited row to the server of cause too. Please explain which functionality you want to implement.

Comment: jquery.jqGrid-4.5.4

Comment: Using free jqgrid version 4.5.4 with jquery 1.10.2. The example shows a way to edit the rows and submit. I am not sure if there is another way that is better but that was good enough for what I need.